# Retrieve only posts from a specific user in wp-admin/edit.php

Tags: posts, query-posts, wp-admin, wp-list-table

I create a role and set capabilities for a group of user.

```
$userdata = array(
    //something
);
$uid = wp_insert_user($userdata);
if(!empty($uid)){
    $blogger = new WP_User($uid);
    //add role
    $capabilities =  array(
        'read' => true,
        'publish_posts' => true,
        'edit_published_posts' => true,
        'delete_published_posts' => true,
        'edit_posts' => true,
        'delete_posts' => true
    );
    add_role('blogger_simple', 'blogger_simple', $capabilities);
    $blogger -> set_role('blogger_simple');
}
```

Now, the user create successfully. I logged in to the system, and create `one` post , just `one` post.

Then I click the menu `Post --> All Posts` and found three columns there `Mine(number) All(number) Published(number)`.

I click All(2), find I can see others posts?
I click Published(2), still 2 posts one is mine the other is by admin
What's more, I search post, got the same results.

That's not I want, I just want to get my posts not by admin and all other user's post. How do I get just my posts when I click `All/Published` link below `All posts` menu, and also the `search box`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You will need to filter that list.

```
function alter_views_wpse_103613($views) {
  $role = 'blogger_simple';
  if (current_user_can($role)) {
    $views = array('mine'=>$views['mine']);
  }
  return $views;
}
add_filter( 'views_edit-post', 'alter_views_wpse_103613' );
```

That filter list is part of the [`WP_List_Table`](http://core.trac.wordpress.org/browser/trunk/wp-admin/includes/class-wp-list-table.php) class if you want to investigate more. Look for the [`views`](http://core.trac.wordpress.org/browser/trunk/wp-admin/includes/class-wp-list-table.php#L245) method.